# Joining a list of strings and a list of integers in a table

Tags: apex, visualforce, pageblocktable

I want to make a table of multiple different arrays of different data types.

How do I join those in the same table?

Simple example:

I want the table

**Value** --  **String** 
1 -- a 
2 -- b 
3 -- c

```
public class tableextension {

    public List<Integer> intArray { get; set; }
    { intArray = new Integer[] { 1, 2, 3 }; }

    public List<String> stringArray { get; set; }
    { stringArray = new String[] { 'a', 'b', 'c' }; }

}
```

with Visualforce:

```
<apex:page controller="tableextension" lightningStylesheets="true" >
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Table">
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!intArray}" var="int">
                <apex:column headerValue="Integer" value="{!int}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Is this possible? Adding another pageBlockTable will create two tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most people use a "Wrapper" to combine the elements into a single list. You can do this:

```
public class tableextension {
  public class Wrapper {
    public Integer intValue { get; set; }
    public String stringValue { get; set; }
    Wrapper(Integer intValue, String stringValue) {
      this.intValue = intValue;
      this.stringValue = stringValue;
    }
  }
  public Wrapper[] data { get; set; }
  public tableextension() {
    data = new Wrapper[0]; // or List<Wrapper>();
    data.add(new Wrapper(1,'a'));
    data.add(new Wrapper(2,'b'));
    data.add(new Wrapper(3,'c'));
  }
}
```

---

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!data}" var="item">
    <apex:column headerValue="Integer" value="{!item.intValue}"/>
    <apex:column headerValue="String" value="{!item.stringValue}"/>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

This is arguably the easiest way do go, and less error-prone than using distinct lists to try and marry them together. However, using your code, we could just make a modification here:

```
public class tablextension {
  public Integer[] intList { get; set; }
  public String[] stringList { get; set; |
  public Integer[] indexes { get; set; }
  public tableextension() {
    intList = new Integer[] { 1, 2, 3 };
    stringList = new String[] { 'a','b','c' };
    indexes = new Integer[] { 0, 1, 2 }; // zero-based array indexes
  }
}
```

And then we iterate over the indexes:

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!indexes}" var="index">
    <apex:column headerValue="Integer" value="{!intList[index]}"/>
    <apex:column headerValue="String" value="{!stringList[index]}"/>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

Be aware that if any of the three lists are too small, you'll get a fatal Visualforce error, while if the two lists we're showing from are too large, the final rows won't be displayed. All the variables must be the same size.

This is why I first recommended a Wrapper design instead. This guarantees that everything will be the same size and you won't run into potentially fatal errors.

Answer (score 2):

You can use integers to index into lists via visualforce using typical notation `myArray[index]`. If I recall correctly, you can also `apex:repeat` over the keyset of a map and then access the values like it were an array.

e.g.

```html
<!-- I think you need to provide your own method to get the keyset, I don't think
     that {!myMap.keyset} works -->
<apex:repeat value="{!getKeyset}" var="key">
    <apex:output value="{!myMap[key]}" />
</apex:repeat>
```

You could use that approach if you had, say, a `Map<Integer, List<Object>>`.

But let's stick to lists, and extend your example a bit to make it a bit clearer how to use this with multiple lists.

```
public class tableextension {
    public List<Integer> intArray { get; set; }
    // Important: We're gonna need to use zero-indexing
    { intArray = new Integer[] { 0, 1, 2 }; }
    
    public List<String> stringArray { get; set; }
    { stringArray = new String[] { 'a', 'b', 'c' }; }

    public List<Date> dateArray { get; set; }
    { dateArray = new Date[] { Date.today(), Date.today().addMonths(1), Date.today().addDays(-4)}; }
}
```

Then, using apex:pageBlockTable...

```html
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!intArray}" var="index">
    <apex:outputText value="{!stringArray[index]}" />
    <!-- The comma and "date" indicate it should be formatted as a date.
         Not 100% sure about the syntax here -->
    <apex:outputText value="0, date, YYYY-MM-DD">
        <apex:param value="{!dateArray[index]}" />
    </apex:outputText>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

The caveat here is that all of your lists need to be the same length (or rather, have at least as many elements as your list of indices).